# Trying to make my default selection for USB c920 webcam work in Gstreamer, but still opens laptop internal cam

Tags: camera, v4l

For the past week I have been trying to get my Logitech c920 to act as my default webcam. Despite everything seeming to be in order, it's just not working.

I have GUVCview and V4L installed. I have Gstreamer and Multimedia selector installed. In Multimedia selector, I have c920 selected as my default webcam. I get there by running root

```
$ sudo gstreamer-properties
```

However, when I open G chat/Hangouts or GUVCview, it still opens up my laptop screen camera and I have to select "New" or "Restart" to open up external cam.
I get this message after running `sudo gstreamer-properties`

```
(gstreamer-properties:2885): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkDialog.has-separator

(gstreamer-properties:2885): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkDialog.has-separator
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'artsdsink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdsink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'glimagesink'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lmjpegsrc'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'qcamsrc'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lsrc'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdmon'
gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosrc'
```

- Could these unavailable plug ins be the problem?
- Could there be a bad setting somewhere?

[image: screenshot]
                            [image: screenshot]

I'm running:

- Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Toshiba Satellite L755
- memory: 3.8 Gib
- processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
- graphics: Intel® Sandybridge Mobile
- OS-type 64bit
- disk: 40.2 GB

#### EDIT #1: Readout on Terminal after running `lsusb`  and  `lusub -t`

```
mike@Mike-Ubuntu12:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b289 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:082d Logitech, Inc. 
mike@Mike-Ubuntu12:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 2, Class=audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 3, Class=audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

#### EDIT #2:

```
$ lsusb -vv
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1179648
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  7
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            416666
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           1333333
        dwFrameInterval( 6)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            54
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                        15
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           720
        dwMinBitRate                 73728000
        dwMaxBitRate                442368000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     1843200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  7
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            416666
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           1333333
        dwFrameInterval( 6)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            54
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                        16
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1600
        wHeight                           896
        dwMinBitRate                114688000
        dwMaxBitRate                688128000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     2867200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  7
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            416666
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           1333333
        dwFrameInterval( 6)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            54
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
        bFrameIndex                        17
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1920
        wHeight                          1080
        dwMinBitRate                165888000
        dwMaxBitRate                995328000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     4147200
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  7
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            416666
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 3)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 5)           1333333
        dwFrameInterval( 6)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0180  1x 384 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0280  1x 640 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0320  1x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       6
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x03b0  1x 944 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       7
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0a80  2x 640 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       8
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0b20  2x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       9
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0be0  2x 992 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting      10
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1380  3x 896 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting      11
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x13fc  3x 1020 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         2
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       2 Streaming
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength           38
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       3
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               5
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 5
        bSourceID               1
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x03
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           3
        bDelay                255 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        16000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0044  1x 68 bytes
        bInterval               4
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           3
        bDelay                255 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        24000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0064  1x 100 bytes
        bInterval               4
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           3
        bDelay                255 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        32000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0084  1x 132 bytes
        bInterval               4
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
```

#### EDIT #3 - JAN 5TH:

```
$ for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/id{Vendor,Product}; do \
    echo -n "$i | "; cat $i; done | sort | column -t
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/idProduct  |  b289
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/idVendor   |  04f2
```

**2nd edit:**

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/bConfigurationValue
1
```

**3rd edit**

```
$ sudo su -c 'echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/bConfigurationValue'
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just an idea, but what about a UDEV rule to disable the detection of your laptop's webcam?

Comment: There is also this method: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189708/how-to-disable-integrated-webcam-and-still-be-able-to-use-an-external-one

Comment: It's a little tricky. I'm going off the 2nd thread link you posted. In his example, the internal webcam is clearly labeled after his laptop model. On my lsusb readout, I'm guessing my laptop cam is Bus 001 Device 003 ( even though I don't know what Chicony is)  AND in lsusb -t, I'm thinking Port 4 is what I want to disable?

Comment: Can you rerun the `lsusb`, use `-v` instead. You can add multiple `-vv` to get more details. Often what is done is you can determine a devices USB manufactuer and the device ids, then use these to block. They should be unique per device.

Comment: Ok, I just ran lsusb -vv and posted in edit.

Comment: After a google search, I find the indeed Chicony electronics is partners with Toshiba. So my guess is this is the one I want to block. Question is how?

Comment: The 2nd link I gave you shows you how to disable the USB dev. once you've identified it. Did you try this?

Comment: Ok, I'm looking at his answer and can't make heads or tails of it. It seems he's using a generic example (cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-6/id{Vendor,Product}) I'm trying to figure out what I would enter, instead of 1-6/id{vendor, product} Ultimately, I want my built in laptop's camera to be disabled, and my USB Logitech c920 webcam to be the default startup on Google Hangouts etc. Am I missing something totally obvious in his post?  I'm looking at my lsusb -t readout, and can't figure out what he means by /1-6/id{Vendor,Product}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the approach that's outlined in this AU Q&A titled: [How to disable integrated webcam and still be able to use an external one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189708/how-to-disable-integrated-webcam-and-still-be-able-to-use-an-external-one), I believe you could disable the built-in camera like so.

#### Example

*(From my Thinkpad T410 Laptop running Fedora 19 now, just as an  example)*

**Step 1:** Start with the `lsusb` output.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c521 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Step 2:** You could run a corresponding command like this to find all the `idProducts` & `idVendor` numbers for the devices above, producing output like this:

```
$ for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/id{Vendor,Product};do \
     echo -n "$i | "; cat $i; done | sort | column -t
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/idProduct    |  0020
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/idVendor     |  8087
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/idProduct  |  c521
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/idVendor   |  046d
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/idProduct  |  1003
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/idVendor   |  17ef
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/idProduct    |  0020
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/idVendor     |  8087
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/idProduct   |  0002
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/idVendor    |  1d6b
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/idProduct   |  0002
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/idVendor    |  1d6b
```

So we can go through this list and find the corresponding `idVendor` and `idProduct` numbers for the same device in the `lsusb` output.

**Step 3:** Picking on my cordless mouse:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c521 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
```

These lines are the corresponding `/sys` lines:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/idProduct  |  c521
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/idVendor   |  046d
```

So we now know that the Logitech mouse is this device under `/sys`:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1
```

**Step 4:** We can see that this device is currently enabled by looking at its `bConfigurationValue`.

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/bConfigurationValue
1
```

To disable the USB device we can set this value to `0`:

```
$ sudo su -c 'echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/bConfigurationValue'
```

And magically my mouse is now disabled. To re-enable it:

```
$ sudo su -c 'echo "1" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/bConfigurationValue'
```

**NOTE:** This exact method can be applied to any USB device, such as your built-in camera.

#### Guvcview still not showing externmal camera as default?

If you look at the help for `guvcview` the `--help` shows the following note.

```
  -d, --device=VIDEO_DEVICE        Video Device to use [default: /dev/video0]
```

So even with our changes above, unless the external camera shows up as `/dev/video0`, `guvcview` will not find this secondary camera as the "default" video device.

I think I would be inclined to change tactics and just call `guvcview` with whatever device I want it to use, instead of bothering with the disabling of the builtin camera.

Comment: Ok, My problem is now when I open GUVCview, it says no camera available. I checked on Configuration Value on External webcam, but that's set to 1. I showed results in edit above^. How do I get this to instinctively open my External Camera. I have it set as default in Multimedia Selctor.

Comment: @Mike - see updates.

Comment: Ok. So strangely enough, my external webcam started working as default. At first I got the "unable to open device" error, but later(perhaps because of reboot) my camera worked. When I open GUVCview, my logitech opens and the built in camera is no longer listed as a device option(which is fine)  HOWEVER: today it was back to the old way. So I had to re-run 'sudo su -c 'echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.4/bConfigurationValue' and got it back to external. This may have been because I installed updates today, idk. Thanks for your help!